# Sort an Array of Objects based on key, and based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Consider this:

```
[{name:'John'},{age:25},{address:'some street'}]
```

As you can see none of the keys are a consistent name, so I cannot use.

```
arr.sort((a,b)=> a.consistentKey < b.consistentKey);
```

How can I go about sorting something like this, by name, and by value?

so the following sorted by key in alphabetical order should be:

```
[{address:'some street'},{age:25},{name:'John'}]
```

Comment: Can explain how would you like to sort it?

Comment: Given the objects do not have consistent property names or types, they are not comparable, and I wonder how you would want to sort them at all.

Comment: @Kind user Consider that the whole object, what difference would it make?... I am adding random key value pairs to an array, but would like to sort them based on either key, or value... How is this possible?

Comment: This whole task doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to build?

Comment: @Thomas no offence, but if you can't help me with this part. I doubt you could help me with the entire project.

Comment: Are all these objects have a single property?

Comment: @JohnSnow I think what Thomas means, is that sorting objects like this is very unusual, and you're probably modelling your data incorrectly. You've got 3 objects in an array, each object having a single property, when it looks like you should have 1 object without an array, with that object containing all 3 properties.

Comment: If there were a 4th object in the array with the value `{ age: 26, address: 'another street' }` would you expect this object to be at index 0 in the sorted array, or index 2? In other words, are the keys of the object to be sorted first, and then any objects with the same keys to be sorted by their values? Or did you have something else in mind? Or is each element in the array an object with only a single property?

Comment: @4castle I understand, I do not have control over the data modelling, I simply need to complete the task. I agree, it is a horrible task.

Comment: @ScottSchupbach there can only be one key and one value per object.

Comment: In that case convert it with `var properObject = Object.assign({}, ...weirdObjectArray);` and don't use the crazy data model you've been given.

Comment: So the task you've been given is to sort this array of objects? Or is there a bigger task, and this is just *your approach* to solve that? And you still did not answer how these items should be sorted. And what is it about the sorting by value when the keys are already unique? And `I am adding random key value pairs to an array` If *you* are doing this, then why do you use this crappy model, how about `{key: "name", value: "John"}`? The sorting logic would immediately get simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of sorting on the basis of key first and then further on values, you can try the following :

```js
var a = [{name:'John'},{age:25},{address:'some street'}];
        
    alert(JSON.stringify(a.sort((a, b) => {
      nameA = Object.keys(a)[0];
      nameB = Object.keys(b)[0];
    
      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      }
    
      // names must be equal
      return 0;
    })));
```

Here I have considered only one key, but you can always extend it to multiple keys and similarly you can further sort on the basis of values too.

Comment: you mind console.logging the answer? alert just shows [object object]

Comment: even console will too print object object except that in chrome. I have stringified the content for debugging. The bottom line is that this code should work.

Comment: console.dir(someObject) will let you unpack the object contents in the console

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the key name using `Object.keys`, then you can get the values you need to perform the comparison:

```
[{name: 'John'}, {age: 25}, {address:'some street'}].sort((a, b) => {
  const keyA = Object.keys(a)[0]
  const valA = a[keyA]
  const keyB = Object.keys(b)[0]
  const valB = a[keyB]

  if (keyA > keyB) {
    return 1
  } else if (keyA < keyB) {
    return -1
  } else /* equal */ {
   if (valA > valB) {
      return 1
    } else if (valA < valB) {
      return -1
    } else /* equal */ {
      return 0
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
input.sort((a, b) => {
  const keya = Object.keys(a)[0];
  const keyb = Object.keys(b)[0];

  return keya.localeCompare(keyb) || a[keya].localeCompare(b[keyb]);
});
```

Using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is both shorter and more robust in the face of different language locales.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I would use. This solution provides a *keys only* sort, a *values only* sort, a *keys then values* sort, and a *values then keys* sort.

```
class FunkySort {
  sort (sortType) {
    switch (sortType) {
      case 'keysOnly':
        return data => this._sortByKey(data);
      case 'valuesOnly':
        return data => this._sortByValue(data);
      case 'valuesPrimary':
        return data => {
          data = this._sortByKey(data);
          return this._sortByValue(data);
        };
      case 'keysPrimary':
        return data => {
          data = this._sortByValue(data);
          return this._sortByKey(data);
        };
    }
  }

  _sortByKey (data) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      var keyA = Object.keys(a)[0];
      var keyB = Object.keys(b)[0];
      return keyA < keyB ? -1 : keyA > keyB ? 1 : 0;
    });
  }

  _sortByValue (data) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      // note that in Node >=v7 you could use `Object.values()`, but not in <v7.0
      var valueA = a[Object.keys(a)[0]];
      var valueB = b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
      return valueA < valueB ? -1 : valueA > valueB ? 1 : 0;
    });
  }
}

const dataArr = [{name:'John'},{age:25},{address:'some street'}];
const fs = new FunkySort();
fs.sort('keysPrimary')(dataArr);
```

Note that `fs.sort` is a curried function. The first call sets the type of sort to be done, so `fs.sort('keysPrimary')` returns a function that takes an array of objects and sorts it first by the values, and then by the keys, resulting in an array of objects sorted by key, and if there are multiple objects with the same key, those are sorted by value.

If you don't need this level of flexibility in the type of sort, then just the `_sortByKey` helper method should suffice.